# Couchbase: python SDK "uppend"

Tags: python, couchbase

I want to do an "uppend_multi": an `append_multi` (http://pythonhosted.org/couchbase/api/couchbase.html#couchbase.bucket.Bucket.append_multi) where some of the keys may not exist. If they do not already exist then the append operation should be an insert. How can I do this? Nothing in the API docs suggests this is supported, but I imagine it is a very common operation.

Right now I am doing this, but it seems so natural of a thing to need to do that I highly doubt this is the best way to do it:

```
def _uppend_multi(bucket, append_dict):
    reinsert_dict = {}
    try:
        bucket.append_multi(append_dict, format = couchbase.FMT_UTF8)

    except CouchbaseError as exc:
        for k, res in exc.all_results.items():
            if res.success:
                pass
            else:
                reinsert_dict[k] = append_dict[k]

    if len(reinsert_dict.keys()) > 0:
        bucket.insert_multi(reinsert_dict, format = couchbase.FMT_UTF8)
```

Comment: The python lib is a wrapper around the libcouchbase. You could look there for this operation. You could also ask the developers - they hang out on irc #libcouchbase. read here: https://github.com/couchbase/libcouchbase

Comment: To make your exception handling a bit less, ugly, you can always use `split_results()`: http://pythonhosted.org/couchbase/api/exceptions.html#couchbase.exceptions.CouchbaseError.split_results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no such "uppend" operation in the Couchbase Python SDK, nor in the lower-level C API (`libcouchbase`).

What you're currently doing is probably a pretty reasonable solution.